# In Scala I can have reference to a private type via implicit conversion

Tags: scala, jodatime, reactive-programming

I've found this interesting behaviour in nscala_time package (scala version of joda-time)

```scala
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.DurationBuilder

object tests {
  val x = 3 seconds
  //> x : is of type com.github.nscala_time.time.DurationBuilder

  val xx: DurationBuilder = 3 seconds
  //> fails to compile: 
  // class DurationBuilder in package time cannot be accessed in package com.github.nscala_time.time
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is implicit conversion from nscala_time Duration to scala.concurrent.Duration
I need this becuase I'm using RxScala and nscala_time in one application.

```scala
// e.g. the following should be implicitly converted
// to nscala_time Duration first
// than to scala.lang.concurrent.Duration
3 seconds
```

nscala_time offers rich time & date api for my application, while I'm using RxScala in the same class for GUI responsivness.
You can download a simple project to play around: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9958045/implicit_vs_private.zip

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can use an implicit conversion? (btw `Duration` in nscala is essentially `org.joda.time.Duration`):

```
scala> import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

scala> implicit class DurationHelper(d:org.joda.time.Duration) {
     | def toScalaDuration = scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.apply(d.getMillis,scala.concurrent.duration.MILLISECONDS)
     | }
defined class DurationHelper

scala> val d = RichInt(3).seconds.toDuration
// toDuration method is defined for com.github.nscala_time.time.DurationBuilder
d: org.joda.time.Duration = PT3S

scala> def exfun(d:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration) = d.toString
exfun: (d: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)String

scala> exfun(d)
res41: String = 3000 milliseconds
```

(not using `import scala.concurrent.duration._` here to avoid name clashes with joda/nlscala stuff)

Comment: That's actually what I've tried to do. However when you write "3 seconds" you get a DurationBuilder (not org.joda.time.Duration). So implicit conversion will not apply. I've prepared a simple project so you can play around: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9958045/implicit_vs_private.zip

Comment: Could you please post a snippet? The only way I can make it work is:
    val x: ScalaDuration = (3 seconds).toDuration

but it's far from elegant solution

Comment: Yes, it's slightly more sophisticated than I thought. Going to update the answer

Comment: nscala_time is not a holy cow, if it's not helpful then just ditch it and work with org.joda.time.Duration directly (that's what I did in similar situations)

Answer (score 1):

From [scala-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/opjgYPAiBHs) group: It's a known issue  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1800